# IndexError: list index out of range in for loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop which is below, unfortunately it throws me an error in the first time itself. i managed to assigned a zero value to the variable but then have this error `xest[i] = xprediction + K * y[i] - np.multiply(H, xprediction)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (1,1)`

```sh
x1 = np.zeros(len(t))
x2 = np.zeros(len(t))
K = np.zeros(len(t))
x1p_1 = np.zeros(len(t))
x2p_1 = np.zeros(len(t))
x1e = np.zeros(len(t))
x2e = np.zeros(len(t)) 
y = np.zeros(len(t))

for i in range (1,25):
    print("",i)
    if i < 10:
        u = 0.25
    else:
        u = 0.0

    x1[i] = x1[i] + (dt*x2[i]) + (dt**2/2)*u
    x2[i] = x2[i] + dt*u + math.sqrt(Q)*np.random.normal()

    y[i] = x1[i] + math.sqrt(R) * np.random.normal()

    PP = (A.dot(PE).dot(A_trans)) + (G.dot(Q).dot(G_trans))
    K = (PP.dot(H_trans)).dot(np.linalg.inv(H.dot(PP.dot(H_trans) + R)))
    ident = np.identity(2)
    PE = (ident - K.dot(H)).dot(PP)

    xprediction = A.dot(xest) + B.dot(u)
       xest[i] = xprediction + K * y[i] - np.multiply(H, xprediction)

    """This equations are basically   
    x1e(i+1) = [1 0] * xest
    x2e(i+1) = [0 1] * xest"""

    sol_1 = np.matrix('%s %s' % (1, 0))
    sol_2 = np.matrix('%s %s' % (0, 1))
    x1e[i] = np.multiply(sol_1, xest[i])
    x2e[i] = np.multiply(sol_2, xest[i])


    print("",x1[i])
```

```sh
  1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-6ccc7c6deb33> in <module>
      6         u = 0.0
      7 
----> 8     x1[i] = x1[i] + (dt*x2[i]) + (dt**2/2)*u
      9     x2[i] = x2[i] + dt*u + math.sqrt(Q)*np.random.normal()
     10 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can somebody explain this to me, I really appreciate that.

Comment: What are `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: Could you show the code for x2? I'm presuming that maybe x2[i] doesn't yet exist?

Comment: that means you're trying to access an element that does not even exist within the range.

Comment: x1 and x2 are empty. 
```bash
x1  = [0.0]
x2  = [0.0]
y = [0.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error is being thrown in the first run of the for loop, it seems like `x1` and `x2` have yet to be assigned values. You can fix this error by appending the arrays instead of using an assignment operator which can be done by writing the following

```
for i in range (1,25):
    print("",i)
    if i < 10:
        u = 0.25
    else:
        u = 0.0

    x1.append((dt*x2[i]) + (dt**2/2)*u)
    x2.append(dt*u + math.sqrt(Q)*np.random.normal())

    y.append(math.sqrt(R) * np.random.normal())
```

There isn't much more I can provide in terms of help, unless you edit your answer to include the declaration and assignment of `x1` and `x2`